# PostgreSQL operator uses index but underlying function does not

Tags: postgresql, index-tuning, json, postgresql-9.4, operator

I'm attempting to use `JSONB` with JDBC, which means that I have to avoid any of the operators which use the '?' character (as the PostgreSQL JDBC driver has no escaping for this character). Taking a simple table:

```
CREATE TABLE jsonthings(d JSONB NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO jsonthings VALUES
    ('{"name":"First","tags":["foo"]}')
  , ('{"name":"Second","tags":["foo","bar"]}')
  , ('{"name":"Third","tags":["bar","baz"]}')
  , ('{"name":"Fourth","tags":["baz"]}');
CREATE INDEX idx_jsonthings_name ON jsonthings USING GIN ((d->'name'));
```

Using the command line I can run a simple select and it uses the index as expected:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT d FROM jsonthings WHERE d->'name' ? 'First';

                                                            QUERY PLAN                                                            
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on jsonthings  (cost=113.50..30236.13 rows=10000 width=61) (actual time=0.024..0.025 rows=1 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ((d -> 'name'::text) ? 'First'::text)
   Heap Blocks: exact=1
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_jsonthings_name  (cost=0.00..111.00 rows=10000 width=0) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=1 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((d -> 'name'::text) ? 'First'::text)
 Planning time: 0.073 ms
 Execution time: 0.047 ms
(7 rows)
```

Since I cannot use the `?` character I resorted to using a **function** which underpins the `?` operator. However, it is not using the index:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT d FROM jsonthings WHERE jsonb_exists(d->'name','First');
                                                            QUERY PLAN                                                            
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on jsonthings  (cost=10000000000.00..10000263637.06 rows=3333334 width=61) (actual time=0.016..3135.119 rows=1 loops=1)
   Filter: jsonb_exists((d -> 'name'::text), 'First'::text)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 10000003
 Planning time: 0.051 ms
 Execution time: 3135.138 ms
(5 rows)
```

Why is this happening, and what can I do to make the function use the index? Note that in reality the table has another 10MM rows in it and I also have `enable_seqscan` turned off so this isn't a case of the planner deciding not to use the index.

In response to a comment I tried using a **custom operator** instead:

```
CREATE OPERATOR ### (
  PROCEDURE = jsonb_exists,
  LEFTARG = jsonb,
  RIGHTARG = text,
  RESTRICT = contsel,
  JOIN = contjoinsel);
```

But that has the same problem:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT d FROM jsonthings WHERE d->'name' ### 'First';
                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on jsonthings  (cost=10000000000.00..10000263637.06 rows=10000 width=61) (actual time=0.012..3381.608 rows=1 loops=1)
   Filter: ((d -> 'name'::text) ### 'First'::text)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 10000003
 Planning time: 0.046 ms
 Execution time: 3381.623 ms
(5 rows)
```

**Update**

The latest PostgreSql driver (as of March 2015) has the ability to escape the `?` character so this specific case is no longer a problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14786469/246260 about how to get around the limitation of question marks (basically define an other operator name).  However, this is really interesting - apparently, the planner is not aware that it can optimize the latter query just as it does with the first one (see cost estimates).

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Unfortunately though the planner doesn't seem to use indexes for custom operators either.  I'll update the question accordingly.

Comment: Do you _have_ to use a `PreparedStatement`? As long as you don't use that, you can use a `?` without any problems.

Comment: I'd be more likely to stick with my current infrastructure (which is way more than just preparedstatements), give up on using PostgreSql to store JSON, and just use a traditional table.  But I'd far prefer to find a real solution to what appears to be a valid issue with PostgreSql (unless I'm seriously misunderstanding something about the planner).

Comment: To me it smells like a bug, it may make sense to visit the bugs mailing list...  Temporarily, you may be able to wrap this statement into a function and call it instead of the statement itself.

Comment: Please provide the `CREATE FUNCTION` statement for `jsonb_exists()`. (Without testing) I would speculate that an `IMMUTABLE` sql function might work.

Comment: `jsonb_exists()` is part of the PostgreSql distribution, no idea where to find its definition.

Comment: @deszo: It's a built-in conceptual limitation of Postgres that index support is bound to *operators*, not functions.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter interesting.  I can confirm it trying the same with some other operators and their implementing functions, too.

Comment: Dear jgm. Can you add a link and/or version number for the updated postgresql JDBC driver that allows escaping the ? please. I can't find a hint at https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/changelog.html

Comment: It is version 1201 of the driver.  Maven repository has it at http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql/

Comment: @jgm could you please tell how to escape '?' character in JDBC statements? I'm using postgresql driver 42.2.1 but, for example, doubling the '?' doesn't help for me (I'm using Spring Data JPA queries).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Supported operators and workaround

The default operator class for GIN indexes on `json` columns `jsonb_ops` only supports these operators [(per documentaion):](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin-builtin-opclasses.html)

> ```
> Name        Indexed Data Type   Indexable Operators
> ...
> jsonb_ops   jsonb               ? ?& ?| @>
> ```

You can achieve this the other way round: Create a **simple `IMMUTABLE` SQL** function using the `?` operator, which can be inlined and will use the index just like the operator itself:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jb_contains(jsonb, text)
  RETURNS bool AS
'SELECT $1 ? $2' LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

This works, I tested in Postgres 9.4 ...

#### Misunderstandings

**However**, you have been asking the **wrong question**. There are two basic misconceptions in your question.

1. The `jsonb` operator `?` cannot be used to search for *values*. Only for *keys* or *array elements*. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE)

   > **Description:**
   >   Does the string exist as a top-level key within the JSON value?

   You got the **wrong operator**, the `WHERE` condition cannot work: <strike>`WHERE d->'name' ? 'First'`</strike>
2. The expression index you have doesn't makes sense either way

   ```
   CREATE INDEX idx_jsonthings_name ON jsonthings USING GIN ((d->'name'));
   ```

   - The expression `d->'name'` returns a `jsonb` value. You would need `d`**`->>`**`'name'` to get the value as `text`.
   - But that would still be pointless. Since the value of the `name` key is a simple string, a GIN index (while possible) makes no sense to begin with.

#### Solutions

You don't need the operator `?` - so no workaround either.
Here are two ways that would actually work:

1. Plain GIN index on `d` and use the "contains" operator **`@>`**:

   ```
   CREATE INDEX idx_jsonthings_d_gin ON jsonthings USING GIN (d);

   SELECT d FROM jsonthings WHERE d @> '{"name":"First"}'
   ```

   You could even use the more [specialized operator class `jsonb_path_ops`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING). See:

   - [How to get particular object from jsonb array in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127689/how-to-get-particular-object-from-jsonb-array-in-postgresql/127786#127786)
2. B-tree expression index on `d->>'email'` and test with good old **`=`**:

   ```
   CREATE INDEX idx_jsonthings_d_email ON jsonthings ((d->>'email'));

   SELECT d FROM jsonthings WHERE d->>'email' = 'First';
   ```

The second index would be considerably smaller and the query faster.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Unfortunately this still carries out a full scan.

Comment: @jgm: [Your new question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/102910/3684) made me look at this once more. Consider the completely rewritten answer.

Comment: Thanks for the rewrite.  I did end up using ``@>`` as per your first solution.