# How to get particular object from jsonb array in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, array, json

I have a field called 'user' that holds a json array that roughly looks like this:

`"user"`:

```
[{ "_id" : "1", "count" : "4" }, { "_id" : "3", "count": "4"}]
```

Now I want a query like:

```
select count from tablename where id = "1"
```

I'm not able to get the particular field `count` from an array of json objects in PostgreSQL 9.4.

Answer (score 29):

It would be much more efficient to store your values in a normalized schema. That said, you can also make it work with your current setup.

#### Assumptions

Assuming this table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (tbl_id int, usr jsonb);
```

"user" is a [reserved word](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) and would require double quoting to be used as column name. Don't do that. I use `usr` instead.

#### Query

The query is not as trivial as the (now deleted) comments made it seem:

```
SELECT t.tbl_id, obj.val->>'count' AS count
FROM   tbl t
JOIN   LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(t.usr) obj(val) ON obj.val->>'_id' = '1'
WHERE  t.usr @> '[{"_id":"1"}]';
```

There are ***3 basic steps***:

#### 1. Identify qualifying rows cheaply

`WHERE  t.usr @> '[{"_id":"1"}]'` identifies rows with matching object in the JSON array. The expression can use a generic GIN index on the `jsonb` column, or one with the more specialized operator class `jsonb_path_ops`:

```
CREATE INDEX tbl_usr_gin_idx ON tbl USING gin (usr jsonb_path_ops);
```

The added `WHERE` clause is **logically redundant**, but it is required to use the index. The expression in the join clause enforces the same condition but only *after* unnesting the array in every row qualifying so far. With index support, Postgres only processes rows that contain a qualifying object to begin with. Does not matter much with small tables, makes a *huge* difference with big tables and only few qualifying rows.

Related:

- [PostgreSQL operator uses index but underlying function does not](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90002/postgresql-operator-uses-index-but-underlying-function-does-not/91007#91007)
- [Index for finding an element in a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18405706/939860)

#### 2. Identify matching object(s) in the array

Unnest with [`jsonb_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html). ([`unnest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) is only good for Postgres array types.) Since we are only interested in actually matching objects, filter in the join condition right away.

Related:

- [How to turn JSON array into Postgres array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54283/how-to-turn-json-array-into-postgres-array/54289#54289)

#### 3. Extract value for nested key `'count'`

After qualifying objects have been extracted, simply: `obj.val->>'count'`.

Answer (score 2):

In postgres 12 or later, you can use [jsonb_path_query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE).

```
WITH cte (
    js
) AS (
    VALUES ('[{ "_id" : "1", "count" : "4" }, { "_id" : "3", "count": "4"}]'))
SELECT
    jsonb_path_query(js::jsonb, '$[*] ? (@._id == "1")') ->> 'count'
FROM
    cte;
```