# Search subkey inside JSONB

Tags: postgresql, json, postgresql-9.6

In a PostgreSQL 9.6 database, I'm using this sql to get 'application' (field) -> 'tour_id.id' (key and subkey in jsonb field)

```
SELECT * 
FROM "payment" WHERE ("payment"."application"#>>'{}')::text 
LIKE '%a43d38d4-9bfb-4ffa-8704-e536f04b0c60%'
ORDER BY "payment"."createdAt" DESC;
```

My id is unique, but really I'd like to do it the right way in Postgres. (I know how to do it with a key, but not with a subkey.)

Example `jsonb` value:

```
[{"tour_id":
   {"id":"a43d38d4-9bfb-4ffa-8704-e536f04b0c60","name":"Terre Sainte 2018"},
   "amount":"500.00",
   "customer_id":{"id":"f492b26d-d260-4bcb-8e96-6532fdf38665","name":"OBAMA John"},
 "id":"5cd8338c-15c2-48c5-b305-9e172bb33a9a"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm using this sql to get 'application' (field) -> 'tour_id.id'

Assuming you meant to ask:

*I'm using this SQL query to retrieve the row where `application #>> '{0, tour_id, id}'` equals the provided UUID.*

.. which already carries half an answer.

If your outer JSON array only has a ***single*** element like your example value implies, use this simple query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   payment
WHERE  application #>> '{0, tour_id, id}' = 'a43d38d4-9bfb-4ffa-8704-e536f04b0c60'
ORDER  BY "createdAt" DESC;
```

Note how I replaced the (assumingly) unneeded fuzziness of
`like '%a43d38d4-9bfb-4ffa-8704-e536f04b0c60%'`
with simpler and faster
`= 'a43d38d4-9bfb-4ffa-8704-e536f04b0c60'`.

Else (for any number of elements in the outer JSON array):

```
SELECT *
FROM   payment
WHERE  application @> '[{"tour_id": {"id":"a43d38d4-9bfb-4ffa-8704-e536f04b0c60"}}]'
ORDER  BY "createdAt" DESC;
```

That's the `jsonb` containment operator `@>`, which can be supported with a generic index or a more specialized `jsonb_path_ops` index. Instructions and links:

- [How to get particular object from jsonb array in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127689/how-to-get-particular-object-from-jsonb-array-in-postgresql/127786#127786)

[The manual hints:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

> For a full description of `jsonb` containment and existence semantics, see [Section 8.14.3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html#JSON-CONTAINMENT).

Comment: thanks, tour_id can be repeated inside the array, in elements 0,1,2 with different values so the right is application @> '[{"tour_id": {"id":"a43d38d4-9bfb-4ffa-8704-e536f04b0c60"}}] ? in that case how to index a subkey, inside in array is possible?

Comment: it's very nice your solution about look for the first element, sometimes i need to look for that:  application #>> '{0, tour_id, id}' ,  it would be nice if posgres can allo me look for  application #>> '{*, tour_id, id}' , because @> maybe is slower, because look in subkeys of subkeys tree?

Comment: @stackdave: Supported with a `json_path_ops` index, the 2nd query should be *fast*. To index *only* (multiple) id values, you need a special expression index, which might be considerably smaller ... If you need help with this index, ask a new question with exact details: is `id` a valid uuid? Typical queries - just what we see here?

Comment: thanks, i've just created a new question, trying give more details about the database logic

Comment: hello again , how can i use   @> to look with like '%Par%'  [{"city":"Paris","country":"FRA"},{"city":"Parana","country":"ARG"}] ; write I another question ? thanks again

Comment: @stackdave: Yes, a new question, please. Comments are not the place.

Comment: I 've written another question

Comment: hi @Erwin I've written the question about like% , hope you have time to answer me, thanks