# Postgresql JSONB Column, how to query for multiple specific elements in a JSON array

Tags: postgresql, json, array

Giving the following JSONB data structure of a `stopInfo` column in a `myTable` table:

```
{
      "stopInfo": [
        {
          "stopType": "Origin",
          "partnerId": "KR01",
          "locationId": "KR57",
          "partnerName": "Seller"
        },
        {
          "stopType": "Destination",
          "partnerId": "225735",
          "locationId": "0301223684",
          "partnerName": "Buyer"
        }
      ]
}
```

How do I write a single select statement to get the `partnerName` of the Origin stop and the Destination stop?

This is as close as I've come.

```
    select (jsonbColumn->'stopInfo'->>'partnerName') as OriginPartner, 
(jsonbColumn->'stopInfo'->>'partnerName') as DestinationPartner
    from myTable;
```

Clearly there's some kind of in-line criteria I need to apply for each column to ensure I'm getting the value out of the right array element, but I'm struggling to find a good example of this simple scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after stitching together a few other questions on Stack Exchange, mainly this one: [How to get particular object from jsonb array in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127689/how-to-get-particular-object-from-jsonb-array-in-postgresql)

```
select origin.value->>'partnerName' as OriginPartner, 
destination.value->>'partnerName' as DestinationPartner
from myTable
join lateral jsonb_array_elements(stopInfo) origin(value) ON origin.value->>'stopType' = 'Origin'
join lateral jsonb_array_elements(stopInfo) destination(value) ON destination.value->>'stopType' = 'Destination';
```