# Caveats of OUTER JOIN on nested JSON value

Tags: postgresql, join, postgresql-9.4, json, exists

I'm writing a query which is supposed to find the elements from a list which DO NOT exist in the DB. My first attempt at this was to use a nested query where the first query fetches the ids, then I `right join` on that query to get what I need, and this works well:

```
select v.id from (
    select distinct json_data ->> 'elementId' as elementId
    from content
    and json_data->> 'elementId' in ('id1', 'id2', 'id3')
) as a
right join (values('id1'), ('id2'), ('id3')) as v(id)
on v.id = a.elementId
where a.elementId is null
```

The above query works perfect except for the fact that I want to I should be able to reduce the nested query to a regular `select` if I do the comparison on `json_data ->> 'elementId'` directly.

My attempt:

```
select v.id
from content a
right join (values('id1'), ('id2'), ('id3')) as v(id)
on json_data ->> 'elementId' = v.id
```

<s>After some debugging I realized that this will never work because the `content` table will always contain a row even if `json_data ->>'elementId'` is `null`.</s>

**Edit:** I had an extra `WHERE` statement which wasn't stated in the question, once I moved this after the `ON` my query was fixed

My question is; Is there a way to avoid using a nested query when wanted to do a `left join` or `right join`  on `JSON` data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (VALUES ('id1'), ('id2'), ('id3')) AS v(id)
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM content WHERE json_data ->> 'elementId' = v.id);
```

Or if you prefer a *join*:

```
SELECT v.id
FROM  (VALUES ('id1'), ('id2'), ('id3')) AS v(id)
LEFT   JOIN content c ON c.json_data ->> 'elementId' = v.id
WHERE  c.json_data IS NULL -- or use the PK column
```

Either is an "anti-join", technically; and both will probably result in the same query plan.

See:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19364694/939860)

Consider upgrading to a current version of Postgres. [9.4 has reached EOL in Feb 2020.](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)

#### Index

But even Postgres 9.4 already supports `jsonb` which (unlike `json`) allows a GIN index to support your query. See:

- [How to get particular object from jsonb array in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127689/how-to-get-particular-object-from-jsonb-array-in-postgresql/127786#127786)
- [What's the proper index for querying structures in arrays in Postgres jsonb?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27708358/939860)

Or if you are focused on this query exclusively, a plain [btree on an expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/indexes-expressional.html) should be the optimum:

```
CREATE INDEX ON content ((json_data ->> 'elementId'));
```

Related:

- [PostgreSQL operator uses index but underlying function does not](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90002/postgresql-operator-uses-index-but-underlying-function-does-not/91007#91007)